# order preserving encryption for numeric data

Tags: c#, .net, security

I need to encrypt numeric data while preserving the order for inequality search. That is, if v1 < v2, ciphertext(v1) < ciphertext(v2). Are there any cryptography library that implements order preserving encryption for numeric data?

Comment: There are encryption systems that may be able to do this ([homomorphic encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption)), but out of curiosity why do you need it?

Comment: I have to store patients clinical data in encrypted form but still be able to support queries with <, > etc on numeric fields

Comment: What database system are you using. SQL Server provides encryption on data columns at rest. The encryption is transparent to any queries being run on the data via authorized procedures (This is not homomorphic encryption, it is just decrypting the data as needed to run the queries).

Comment: SQL Server cell level encryption does not protect against DBA from looking at the data. That is why I'm looking at something like homomorphic encryption.

Comment: homomorphic encryption does not protect you from administators either. They just run whatever would be run to display the data to a authorized end user.